# How to assign value to a state variable inside fetchData?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

This is `fetchData` function used in my ReactJS class. It makes a call to API which returns an integer.

```
fetchData = () => {

    const url = "http://localhost:8000?"+
      'mytime='+this.state.mytime+
      '&mytype='+this.state.mytype;

    fetch(url, {
      method: "GET",
      dataType: "JSON",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      }
    })
    .then((resp) => {
      return resp.json()
    })
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({
          chartData: [...this.state.chartData, {field1: this.state.field1, field2: data.field2}]
      })
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error, "catch the hoop")
    })
};
```

I don't know how to assign this result (`data.field2`) to `this.state.field2 = data.field2`. How can I do it inside this code part:

```
.then((data) => {
      this.setState({
          chartData: [...this.state.chartData, {field1: this.state.field1, field2: data.field2}]
      })
    })
```

Comment: Can you provide shape of your state? It looks like you are trying to set `this.state.field1` inside `this.chartData` which probably makes me think that you didn't get the JS destructuring concept. Can you post your previous state as json before running request, and EXPECTED state after request is run? I can then help you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
state = {
  chartData: ['A', 'B',
    {
      field1: 'C',
      field2: ''
    }
  ]
}
```

```js
.then((data) => {
 const {chartData} = this.state;
 console.log(chartData[2].field2=data)
})
```

I try to set with this condition